# Regularly check a property of a SharePoint item with Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

I am using powershell to check, if a SharePoint I just added has changed. To do so, I first add the item via

```
$spFile = $spFiles.Add(...)
```

after that I regularly do this:

```
$spFile.Item["propertyName"]
```

The result is the same every time, even if I change the property in SharePoint. So I guess I have to refresh the item in Powershell. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the document library once again and then only you can get the changed value. It stores in cache, Something like this you need to do

```
 $library = $web.Lists["DocumentLibrary"]
 $spFiles= $library.Items | where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"}
 foreach ($spFile in $spFiles) {
       $spFile.Item["propertyName"]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I hoped there was an easier way, but this works:

    $item = $spWeb.GetListItem($spFile.ServerRelativeUrl)